Did split screen function exist before 1970?
I know the story about Engelbard and his presentation, in which a proto-window mode for text output was demonstrated.
But. Was this really the first time multi-window mode was used?
CAD had a screen divided into a drawing field and an on-screen keyboard in the 1960s.

I imagine that some CAD software from the 1960s might well have been able to split the screen in half and output two drawings on one screen.
It could, but did it?
Does anyone know of examples of splitting the screen into two (with the same type of content) before Engelbard's presentation?

This might get better answers over on Retrocomputing SE

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s). At a minimum, all questions should explain why Wikipedia is insufficient.

When did VI and Emacs add split screen?

They both introduced in 1976.

History of Science and Math might be interested as well. I don't think this is off-topic here though. I'd say its up to the Author if they want this migrated.

If you were to try to find the answer to this question in a library, would your first thought be to go to the History section? Just because something happened in the past doesn't make it History.

On the one hand we should encourage more questions about anything other than political or military history, so this question is an asset. OTOH, I recommended moving it exactly because we have few questions of this kind, and the querent is more likely to get an answer elsewhere. I think asking where the question will get a good answer is a better way to approach it than essentialist discussions of what is or is not a history question.
